# SQL Inner Join for 2 Parents - Child - SubChild Tables Custom Query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I'm looking for solution to get the data on the sub child in table.
Basically, this is my scenario.

I have 4 tables.

table_parent1 (parent) looks like this:

```
| id | name  | active |
| 1  | Oscar | yes    |
| 2  | Pablo | yes    |
```

table_parent2 (parent) looks like this:

```
| id | name  | active |
| 1  | Feliz | yes    |
| 2  | Petro | yes    |
```

table2 (child):

```
| id | type  | active | table_parent1_fk | table_parent2_fk |
| 1  | type1 | yes    | 1                | 1
| 2  | type2 | yes    | 1                | 2
| 3  | type23| yes    | 2                | 1
| 4  | type23| yes    |                  |
```

table3 (sub child)

```
| id | otherInfo | table2_fk |
| 1  | info1     | 1         |
| 2  | info2     | 2         |
```

In my original code, I'm using left join but the problem is, I can only access the child and sub child tables.

```
SELECT t.id, t.otherInfo, t.table2_fk, t1.type as type, t2.name as parent1
FROM table3 t 
LEFT JOIN table2 t1 ON t.table2_fk = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table_parent1 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t.id = 1
```

But my problem is to be able to access the data from `table_parent1` & `table_parent2` which are the parent, I want a result something like this.

Expected

```
| id | parent1  | parent2 | type  | otherInfo |
| 1  | Oscar    | Felix   | type1 | info1     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Include it in the `join`:

```
SELECT t.id, t.otherInfo, t.table2_fk, t1.type as type
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2. table1_fk LEFT JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t3.table2_fk = t2.id
WHERE t2.id = 1
```

Comment: Hello, I updated the question and added clarification. Basically, it has 2 parents that I need to get the data through table 2.